# Parsing GPS($GPRMC)... Significance of Validity

Tags: microcontroller, gps

In "$GPRMC,220516,A,5133.82,N,00042.24,W,173.8,231.8,130694,004.2,W*70"

I know that the third argument 'A', is for valid data, but what does validity even mean, because you get an A even when some of the information is missing.

Does an 'A', guarantee valid data?
Should i just discard data with a 'V' or can i still squeeze some useful data out of it?

Comment: You're going to have to specify what data format is expected, examples of when "the data is missing" to give people enough to go on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @Leon Heller Understanding communication protocols commonly used by electronic devices most certainly is part of electronic design.

Comment: @user1767423 What does the datasheet for your receiver say about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular NMEA sentence is a "Recommended minimum specific GPS/Transit data" data stream. "A" or "V" is a receiver warning. http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#rmc

I would ignore all "V" sentences and see what useful data you have left.